# Django Form - Getting last record value from database as dynamic default or initial value for form field

Tags: python-3.x, django, date, django-models, django-forms

I'm new in Python/Django with basic understanding and moving my steps slowly. This is my first question in stackoverflow. I've learned a lot from the previously discussed posts. Thanks to all who asked questions and special thanks to all those who contributed to such helpful answers. I searched and read a lot and tried to understand but could not figure out my way ahead on the following issue.

I have a form for Transaction entry with the following fields.

```
==> Date
==> Farmer_num
==> purchase_qty
==> tr_rate
```

I need to enter many records (500+ for a date) with the same date and same price (tr_rate). Instead of selecting date from datepicker and writing price (tr_rate) on entry form every time, i want to get them as default/initial value when form loads for new entry. This will save my time as well as prevent from entering the wrong date and price.

When the form loads, in the date field, I want the last entry date as initial/default date from Trans table. For example if the last entry date was 2020-08-08, form should load with this date. When that date's entry is finished, I select another date manually e.g. 2020-08-12 for another entry and after that form should populate 2020-08-12 for further entries till next manual change. This date should be retrieved from the Trans table.

Prices change from time to time normally in 3 months for this case. When a new rate applies that is added to the Rate table. When the form is loaded i want the latest rate based on apply_date. Apply date also stores future rates that should be applied while entering new entry. For example :

```
Apply_Date ==> Purchase_Rate
2020-01-01 ==> $ 0.85
2020-03-01 ==> $ 0.90
2020-06-01 ==> $ 0.95
2020-09-01 ==> $ 1.00
2021-01-01 ==> $ 0.90
2021-03-01 ==> $ 0.95
2021-06-01 ==> $ 1.00
2021-09-01 ==> $ 1.05
```

If the last entry date Trans table is 2020-04-06, for new entry, Trans form should load with date 2020-04-06 and rate $ 0.90.
If the last entry date Trans table is 2020-09-01, for new entry, Trans form should load with date 2020-09-01 and rate $ 1.00

Form is working fine without this feature. But, I have no clues how I can implement the required change and which file needs to be modified to achieve this and how. I'm sorry if i could not explain my issue in the way it should be.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Following are my files.

Rate App > models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Rate(models.Model):
    apply_date = models.DateField()
    purchase_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    m_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    w_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

    @property
    def default_buy_rate(self):
        return self.purchase_rate
```

Trans App > models.py

```
from django.db import models
from rate.models import Rate

class Trans(models.Model):
    tr_date = models.DateField() 
    farmer_num = models.ForeignKey('account.Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  account app directly.
    purchase_qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)       
    tr_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    @property
    def purchase_total(self):
        return self.purchase_qty*self.fat*self.tr_rate
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Trans, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_default_buy_rate()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_default_buy_rate()
        super(Trans, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_default_buy_rate(self):
        if self.rate and not self.tr_rate:
            self.tr_rate = self.rate.buy_rate
```

Trans App > forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Trans

class TransForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Trans           
        fields = ('tr_date', 'farmer_num', 'purchase_qty', 'tr_rate')
        labels = {
            'tr_date':'Date',
            'farmer_num':'Ref. Number',
            'purchase_qty':'Buy Qty.',
            'tr_rate':'Buy Rate',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['farmer_num'].empty_label = "Select"
```

Trans App > views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Trans
from .forms import TransForm

def trans_form(request, id=0):         
    if request.method =="GET":          
        if id==0:               
            form_trans = TransForm() 
        else:               
            trans = Trans.objects.get(pk=id)
            form_trans = TransForm(instance=trans)
        return render(request, "trans/trans_form.html",{'form_trans':form_trans})
    else:
        if id==0:               
            form_trans = TransForm(request.POST)            
        else:               
            trans = Trans.objects.get(pk=id)
            form_trans = TransForm(request.POST, instance=trans)                    
        
        if form_trans.is_valid():               
            form_trans.save()
        else:               
            return render(request, "trans/trans_form.html",{'form_trans':form_trans})               
        return redirect('/trans/list')
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line here (in views.py) is the line which instantiates a new form:

```
def trans_form(request, id=0):         
if request.method =="GET":          
    if id==0:               
        form_trans = TransForm()
```

I would get the latest entered record, then use that as the instance to instantiate the form, so the code would be:

```
def trans_form(request, id=0):         
if request.method =="GET":          
    if id==0:
        last_record = Trans.objects.latest('Date')
        form_trans = TransForm(instance=last_record)
```

Documentation for `latest()` can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried the way you've given, It fills from completely using the last record. But i need only date from Trans table not all. I want other fields empty beside date and price. Seconday, i need price from Rate table not from Trans table because price change depends on date field of Rate table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've figureout the somehow workable solution of my problem. I'm posting it here as it may be useful for the new django users in future. I've modified the Trans > views.py with following and now getting what i've expected. Still not able to get the matching rate with entry date. Thanks Mamdouh Waleed for your answer as it game hint to find this solution.

```
def trans_form(request, id=0):
   
if request.method =="GET":

    if id==0:

        # To get initial date and rate for entry form
        last_trans_record = Trans.objects.latest('id')
        last_rate_record = Rate.objects.latest('id')         
        auto_tr_date =  (last_trans_record.tr_date)
        auto_tr_rate =  (last_rate_record.buy_rate)           

        form_trans = TransForm(initial={'tr_date':auto_tr_date, 'tr_rate':auto_tr_rate})
```